# How can I animate the road in iPhone Xcode?

Tags: iphone

I am going to animate the road, simply calling 1 image again and again from top to bottom.  Can anyone suggest how this is possible?

Comment: What does that mean... animate the road? Are you trying to move a static image of a road from the bottom to the top repeatedly to get the effect of a moving 'road view'?

Comment: yes, when i press the button(go) then tha road automatically animated like simple games.....Yes static image.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at a UIScrollView. Put a UIImageView in it, then use the following code:

```
-(void)scroll{
    CGPoint currentPoint = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y + 1);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];

    if(scrollPoint.y == scrollView.contentSize.height+5)//If we've reached the bottom, reset slightly past top, to give ticker look
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake (0,-125)];
    }
}
```

Run that code with a looping NSTimer and you'll be set :)